# Canvas color bound to property (Kivy book): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

This code is in the book *Kivy – Interactive Applications and Games in Python - Second Edition* by Roberto Ulloa.

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<Subtitle@Label>:
    bcolor: .1, .1, .1, 0
    halign: 'center'
    font_size: '20px'
    size: self.texture_size[0]+20, self.texture_size[1]+20
    y: 50

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bcolor

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

The class `Subtitle` in the `subtitle.kv` file is derived from `Label` and is used to display subtitles in a video player (the player project is a tutorial which takes a full section of the book.)

`bcolor` is used from the Python code in `video.py` to change the opacity of the subtitles.

```
def display_subtitle(self, sub):
    self.sub = sub
    self.slabel.text = sub['content']
    self.slabel.bcolor = .1, .1, .1, .8
```

The full code can be found [here](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781785286926/commit/5ae264b685cffe433f205f2116332a19aada0e72#a82cce1ee24d8e22062399b4432fd9ed465fbe6a) and [here](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781785286926/commit/5ae264b685cffe433f205f2116332a19aada0e72#9e9f40915c43d0068ba808dc5a3cd7adbac57703).

The two last lines change the attributes of the a `Subtitle` instance named `slabel`. As the code is written it doesn't run. Error:

```
[WARNING] stderr:      11:        Color:
[WARNING] stderr: >>   13:            rgba: self.bcolor
[WARNING] stderr:      14:
[WARNING] stderr:      15:        Rectangle:
[WARNING] stderr: ...
[WARNING] stderr: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What is the reason `self.bcolor` is equal to `None`?

---

Python 3.6.1 - Kivy 1.10.0 - Windows 7 (64 bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to find the solution (this is book to learn Kivy), so you may appreciate this post if you are searching desperately...

`bcolor` must be a Kivy property, and this can be done in the Python code. As there is no py file associated with the kv file, it can be done where `Subtitle` is used, in `video.py`. The class has to be declared using Python syntax. I moved the base class declaration from kv to py (so I removed `@Label` from `<Subtitle@Label>` in the kv file and added this in `video.py`:

```
...
Builder.load_file('video.kv')
Builder.load_file('subtitle.kv')

class Subtitle(Label):                   <--------------
    bcolor = ListProperty(None)          <--------------

class Video(KivyVideo):
    image = ObjectProperty(None)
    surl = StringProperty(None)

    def on_state(self, instance, value):
    ...
```

and that works:

[image]